Can we replace Uni endpoint resource responses with non-Uni responses when no orchestration needed
I've a question regarding the proper use of Unis in Quarkus enpoints
The following code examples are there to illustrate this ...
Example
Code example 1
The following uses Uni as a response type, so execution "would be" performed
on the IO thread.  However, the @Transactional forces it to run on a worker
thread.
@GET
@Path("/items")
@Transactional
public Uni<Response> getItems(@QueryParam("item-id") int id) {
    return getItemFromDatabase()
            .chain(x -> getItemInformationByName(x))
            .map(x -> Response.ok(x).build());
}

public Uni<String> getItemFromDatabase() {
    return Uni.createFrom().item(() -> {
        // perform database SELECT operation
        // ...
        return "some-items";
    });
}

public Uni<String> getItemInformationByName(String name) {
    return Uni.createFrom().item(() -> {
        // get item information based on its name
        return "item-information";
    });
}

There are 2 calls to fetch data from a database, each returning a Uni:

getItemFromDatabase()
getItemInformationByName()

However, both rely on each other, that is, getItemInformationByName()
needs the name of the item to make its database call.
Code example 2
The following code example picks up the fact both calls to the database rely on
each other and simply calls each method one after another:
@GET
@Path("/items")
@Transactional
public Response getItem(@QueryParam("item-id") int id) {
    String item = getItemFromDatabase(id);
    String itemInformation = getItemInformationByName(item);
    return Response.ok(item + itemInformation).build();
}

public String getItemFromDatabase(int id) {
    // perform database SELECT operation
    // ...
    return "some-items";
}

public String getItemInformationByName(String name) {
    // get item information based on its name
    return "item-information";
}

Furthermore:

the response type has now been replaced with a simple Response
the method calls don't need to return Uni

... that's because the @Transactional makes the execution to run on the worker
thread anyway and (in addition) there is nothing to orchestrate (both method
calls rely on each other), which is (as far as I know), the main point of using
Mutiny and its Uni in the first place.
As a result, we can ditch using Uni on the method calls and the enpoint
resource and just use Response.
Code example 3
Say we now have the opportunity to also fetch the item information from the
database only using the item's ID. So we could now replace using
our getItemInformationByName() with getItemInformationById()
We can now, in fact, orchestrate 2 concurrent calls to the database and would
have valid reason to apply a Uni:
@GET
@Path("/items")
@Transactional
public Uni<Response> getItems(@QueryParam("id") int id) {
    return Uni
            .join()
            .all(getItemFromDatabase(id), getItemInformationById(id))
            .andCollectFailures()
            .map(xs -> Response.ok(xs.get(0) + xs.get(1)).build());
}

public Uni<String> getItemFromDatabase(int id) {
    return Uni.createFrom().item(() -> {
        // perform database SELECT operation
        // ...
        return "some-items";
    });
}

public Uni<String> getItemInformationById(int id) {
    return Uni.createFrom().item(() -> {
        // get item information based on its name
        return "item-information";
    });
}

Now we're returning a Uni from each of the method calls and finally from the
endpoint resource.
The execution is performed on the worker thread. This shouldn't change anyway
since our database calls are blocking anyway (indicated through the
@Transactional annotation).
Question
My question(s) would be whether the code in "code example 2" is correct, in the
sense that we can (in this case) simply replace the use of Uni with a
non-Uni response and whether "example 2" showcases a valid reason to use Uni
given the above situation.
